# aligning text to top of webpage in html code using css

Tags: html, css, margin, text-alignment

I have this css code:

```
.post {
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    margin-left: 2em;
    margin-right: 2em;
    text-align: center;
}

.post p{
    max-width: 1200px;
    padding: .5em;
    text-align: justify;
    margin: 0;
    top: 1.25em;
}

.post h1{
    text-align: center;
}
```

and have this in html:

```
<div class="post">  
 <h1>Title of Sample Work 2</h1>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam dapibus id nisl ut suscipit. Nullam vel justo tellus. Suspendisse vehicula rhoncus nunc sed accumsan. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Mauris vel dolor velit. Phasellus finibus massa mauris, at interdum nisl luctus at. Etiam porttitor, metus non dapibus pretium, orci arcu pretium nulla, eget congue augue libero at lectus. Mauris pretium urna tristique, laoreet enim rhoncus, euismod tortor.</p>
</div>
```

And this is what I see:

[image]

Why there is so much margin at the top and the text title is so down?
You can see an example of the actual page on the web here:
http://www.nanogomo.com/sample1.html

It is interesting that if I add more content to it, it pushes the text up.

Comment: its about how you added rest of the code... , but that code is not added here - update your question ..

Comment: The CSS file is huge, so I cannot add it here. You can see the whole thing at: http://www.nanogomo.com/sample1.html

Comment: I checked your link. It look well. It is not as same as your picture

Comment: Did you look at it on a computer or on a phone? On phone, it looks fine, but on a computer, it looks bad with lots of margin at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the #wrapper has display:flex and has a before. You should you remove the following:

```
#wrapper::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
}
```

The flex container contained 3 elements home-back, post and before. Before is absolutely positioned so it is removed from the normal flow (doesn't take space). Before (with no width) and post are positioned on the main ax (vertical because direction is flex column) with justify-items: space-between (main ax is vertical).

Comment: I did that, but no effect!

Comment: I tried it on your actual page with the developer tools inspector in firefox and worked (main.css line 1142). Could you show me the updated page?

Comment: You are right, it works :)  
Can you please explain what those lines that you suggested to remove do?

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

use margin top and give value according to the need.

```
.post h1{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -7px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a value to margin and padding:

```
.post h1{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```